# How to Skip over divs?

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-mobile

I am doing a mobile html5 / jquery quiz where I preload 
all the questions from the server into one html file, then
have buttons to move back and forth between the questions.
Works nice, but now I am needing to skip certain questions
if the person answers "no" via a radio yes/no input to 
question 20, then 21 and 22, doesn't need to be shown.
How can I do this? this is the code snipplet I been using:

JSFIDDLE:

http://jsfiddle.net/gN9Xg/

Want to skip over question 2 if the person answers "no" on question 1

```
    function doSubmit(obj)
    {
        $(obj).parents(".question").first().next().show();
        $(obj).parents(".question").first().hide();
    }


<div class="question" id="question11" >

<input type="text" name="question11.1" qid="question11" />


<input type=submit id="button"    value="Submit" onclick='doSubmit(this)' />
```

Comment: For the `doSubmit()` function, I would chain the two statements together like this `$(obj).parents(".question").first().hide().next().show();`.

Comment: Your question needs a demo, on http://jsfiddle.net?

Comment: I agree with @undefined. Post the HTML and jQuery/JavaScript that you are concerned with.

Comment: sure, http://jsfiddle.net/gN9Xg/

Comment: What you currently have is a bit naive. One possible solution is to build an array of all questions and use that to find the next question. This way you can "remove" a question from your array.

Comment: The user has the ability to go back with the button, and to change an answer before the final submit.  so if the user answers "no" on question #1, then when they get to question #5 they hit back 5 times to question #1 and answer yes, question 2 will need to show up (visible)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To achieve such thing with minimal changes to the HTML, you can set a class, e.g. "skipper" for the element that will cause such a skip, then the element value will be a number that determines how many questions to skip.

For example to have the answer "No" cause a skip, have such HTML:

```
<select name="question1.1" class="skipper">
    <option  name="question1.1" ano="1" qid="question1" value="0" checked/>Yes
    <option  name="question1.1" ano="1" qid="question1" value="1"  />No
</select>
```

Since you don't really use this value elsewhere, it should be fine.

Now to use it, have such code instead:

```
function doSubmit(obj)
 {
    var oQuestion = $(obj).parents(".question").first();
    var skipCount = parseInt(oQuestion.find(".skipper").val(), 10);
    if (isNaN(skipCount) || skipCount < 0)
        skipCount = 0;
    var oNext = oQuestion.next();
    for (var i = 0; i < skipCount; i++)
        oNext = oNext.next();
    oNext.data("prev_index", oQuestion.index());
    oNext.show();
    oQuestion.hide();
}

function backToPrev(obj)
{
    var oQuestion = $(obj).parents(".question").first();
    var index = parseInt(oQuestion.data("prev_index"), 10);
    if (isNaN(index) || index < 0)
        oQuestion.prev().show();
    else
        $(".question").eq(index).show();
    oQuestion.hide();
}
```

​As you can see, the code look for a "skipper" value and also assign the index of the question to get back to.

[Updated fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/gN9Xg/3/).

Answer (score 0):

Each answer will need some indication as to what to do when it is selected. put a `data-next` attribute on answers which should skip and set the attribute value to the id of the next required question.

Now, when an answer is selected check its `data-next` attribute, if present set the next question to the selected id otherwise proceed as you now do.

Backing up also requires some changes. You need to skip back until you find a question whose style.display is non 'none'.

The essential idea is to use the display style setting to indicate what questions are answered and `data-next` attributes on answers to select the questions to answer.

Hope that allows you to proceed.