# Skip to div with radio button

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

So someone asked something very similar, but i need that the user click on a button instead of have a select box.

[How to Skip over divs?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13105627/how-to-skip-over-divs)

This functions work fine for select box, fiddle with the [answer](http://jsfiddle.net/gN9Xg/3/)

```
function doSubmit(obj)
 {
    var oQuestion = $(obj).parents(".question").first();
    var skipCount = parseInt(oQuestion.find(".skipper").val(), 10);

    if (isNaN(skipCount) || skipCount < 0)
      skipCount = 0;

    var oNext = oQuestion.next();

    for (var i = 0; i < skipCount; i++)
      oNext = oNext.next();

    oNext.data("prev_index", oQuestion.index());
    oNext.show();
    oQuestion.hide();
}

function backToPrev(obj)
 {
       var oQuestion = $(obj).parents(".question").first();
       var index = parseInt(oQuestion.data("prev_index"), 10);

       if (isNaN(index) || index < 0)
         oQuestion.prev().show();
       else
         $(".question").eq(index).show();

       oQuestion.hide();
 }
```

I've tried to change the select box to radio input, but i think the value it's not passing, because if i choose yes or no the div that appears is always the same. (Should be question 2 to yes, and question 3 to no) [fiddle with problem](http://jsfiddle.net/5rXn7/5/)

Can someone guide me ?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Start by validating your HTML; you have some structural errors that may interfere with things, like the missing `</option>` end tags. And avoid creating new attributes; those may not always work.

Comment: @MrLister the invalid HTML belongs to the OP of the linked question, pretty sure Mr. Nibbler here has different HTML altogether and as for the new attributes you're right and it's my fault, wasn't aware of jQuery `.data()` back then. :/

Comment: @ShadowWizard Ehm, the "fiddle with problems" that Nibbler mentions doesn't occur in the linked question, so I assumed this was original work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The key here is to have the "skip" data embedded somehow into each relevant button.

It can be done using plain buttons:

```
<button type="button" onclick="doSubmit(this);">Yes</button>
<button type="button" data-skip="1" onclick="doSubmit(this);">No</button>
```

Where the "No" button will cause one question to be skipped.

To support this, the function should be changed to this:

```
function doSubmit(obj)
{
    var sender = $(obj);
    var oQuestion = sender.parents(".question").first();

    //first, try directly from sender:
    var skipCount = parseInt(sender.data("skip") || "");
    if (isNaN(skipCount)) {
        //try from parent
        skipCount = parseInt(oQuestion.find(".skipper").val(), 10);
    }

    if (isNaN(skipCount) || skipCount < 0)
        skipCount = 0;
    var oNext = oQuestion.next();
    for (var i = 0; i < skipCount; i++)
        oNext = oNext.next();
    oNext.data("prev_index", oQuestion.index());
    oNext.show();
    oQuestion.hide();
}
```

[Updated fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/gN9Xg/4/).